# Landing pages defined by attribute for Magento

Tags: magento, catalog

i'm looking for solution how to have a landing page with products which are filter by some attribute (ie. Brand = Addidas). I was checking advanced search but it doesnt provide layered navigation, which is requested by client.

What I found is the free module http://fishpig.co.uk/attribute-splash-pages.html. It seems to be working, but for each combination of attribute X attribute value I need to configure something in database. It's not useful if you need to maintain thousands of combinations.

My another idea is to review catalog/layer model to remove filtering by category but it probably destroy something :)

Have you any idea or direction where would I go?

Thanks, Jaro.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have a look at http://yoast.com/landing-pages-module-magento/

i've used both and find fishpigs much better for manual creation of optimised pages, but for blasting out auto landing pages yoast is ideal.